# What is the best way to track runtime error in a code

Tags: python

This code is representing the movement of two pawns on a chess board as each on is taking turns. Pawns move only foreword only one square at a time . They can't be in the same column. To win the pawn must reach other side of the board first or to capture the other pawn according to the chess rules.

I run the code through a online judge system and it is passing all the test but one. On this particular test is giving me runtime error.

I tried all the possible variation of the input that I can think off and yet no success. This is how the input looks w - white, b - black and there are different variations.

```
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - b - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- w - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
```

```
matrix = [[x for x in input().split()] for row in range(8)]  # matrix 8x8

chess_col = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']  # reference list of the chess columns
 
chess_row = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]  # reference list of the chess rows 
row_w, col_w, row_b, col_b = 0, 0, 0, 0
square = []  # to store reference values of chess col and row for calculating the final position of the winning pawn. 

win = False
promoted = False

# for loop to determine position of the pawns
for row in range(8):
    for col in range(8):
        if matrix[row][col] == 'w':
            row_w = row
            col_w = col

        if matrix[row][col] == 'b':

            row_b = row
            col_b = col
# starting with white pawn
while True:
    # check if black pawn position is in one of diagonals on the next row 
    if matrix[row_w - 1][col_w - 1] == 'b' or matrix[row_w - 1][col_w + 1] == 'b':
        win = True
        winning_pawn = 'White'
        # taking the reference values 
        row = [chess_row[x] for x in range(len(chess_row)) if x == row_b]
        col = [chess_col[x] for x in range(len(chess_col)) if x == col_b]
        square.append(col[0] + str(row[0]))
        break
    
    # moving the pawn in the matrix(only foreword)
    matrix[row_w][col_w] = '-'
    row_w -= 1
    matrix[row_w][col_w] = 'w'
    
    # if the pawn reach end of the board
    if row_w == 0:
        promoted = True
        winning_pawn = 'White'
        row = [chess_row[x] for x in range(len(chess_row)) if x == row_w]
        col = [chess_col[x] for x in range(len(chess_col)) if x == col_w]
        square.append(col[0] + str(row[0]))
        break

    if matrix[row_b + 1][col_b - 1] == 'w' or matrix[row_b + 1][col_b + 1] == 'w':
        win = True
        winning_pawn = 'Black'
        row = [chess_row[x] for x in range(len(chess_row)) if x == row_w]
        col = [chess_col[x] for x in range(len(chess_col)) if x == col_w]
        square.append(col[0] + str(row[0]))
        break

    matrix[row_b][col_b] = '-'
    row_b += 1
    matrix[row_b][col_b] = 'b'

    if row_b == 7:
        promoted = True
        winning_pawn = 'Black'
        row = [chess_row[x] for x in range(len(chess_row)) if x == row_b]
        col = [chess_col[x] for x in range(len(chess_col)) if x == col_b]
        square.append(col[0] + str(row[0]))
        break

if win:
    print(f"Game over! {winning_pawn} win, capture on {''.join(square)}.")

elif promoted:
    print(f"Game over! {winning_pawn} pawn is promoted to a queen at {''.join(square)}.")
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please [edit] your question and copy and paste the full message. Also, what test is failing?

Comment: The input is matrix 8x8 each position represented by dashes and two positions for the white pawn and the black pawn.

Comment: I think we understand that. What is the error you get? Or can you see the input board that causes the error? Or, as one example, what if you have no `w` or `b` on the board? What should the code do?

Comment: I'm getting only 'Runtime Error'. The judge system is not showing the test that was failed. From 10 tests only one is not passing. Actually the idea behind is that I have to look and to find the mistake in the code that why the system is not giving the at out input is failing.

Comment: The point is that I tried all the possible inputs that I could come up with. I went to every piece of the code but I couldn't find anything wrong. I can rewrite the code trying a different approach but for me is important to know what goes wrong whit that one so I can avoided in future.

Comment: Test #7 (Runtime error)
Time used: 0.050 s
Memory used: 0.00 MB This is what the message I get

Comment: Runtime Error (RE): Your program failed during the execution (segmentation fault, floating point exception...)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the end columns for bought pawns. if the pawn position is on column 0 or 7 I was checking in bought directions for the other pawn and in this way I was going out of the matrix range during one of the checks.

```
if matrix[row_w - 1][col_w - 1] == 'b' or matrix[row_w - 1][col_w + 1] == 'b'
```

this expression I was using to check the position of the other pawn

After correction:

```
    if col_w - 1 < 0:
        if matrix[row_w - 1][col_w + 1] == 'b':
            'some code'

    elif col_w + 1 > 7:
        if matrix[row_w - 1][col_w - 1] == 'b':
           'some code'
    else:
        if matrix[row_w - 1][col_w - 1] == 'b' or matrix[row_w - 1][col_w + 1] == 'b':
           'some code
```

This is when the black pawn is attacking. Same logic is for white one.
Changing the code in this way gave me 100%